# Is it possible to charge and transfer files to an Android phone with a usb-c hub?

Tags: usb, usb-on-the-go, google-pixel

I'm considering buying a usb-c hub to use with my Android phone (Google Pixel), so that I can charge my phone, use a flash drive and a USB keyboard at the same time - all using the phone's single usb-c port.

However, the hubs I've seen sometimes have lists of compatible devices and these lists mention only laptops and not phones. I wonder why, is there anything special about laptops or phones that the accessories aren't compatible? I've seen articles saying that Android's USB can't do OTG and charging at once.

Comment: Phones are not typically USB hosts, in order to connect the devices you want, the device must identify itself as a USB host

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Being a fellow Google Pixel user myself, I can say with 100% confidence that the phone is absolutely capable of providing a charge and transferring files at the same time. It may not be the quickest charge or transfer if your aim is to have both at once, but it supports it nonetheless.