# How can I successfully use a USB-C hub with an Android tablet?

Tags: external-keyboard, usb-c

I got an [Android tablet](https://smile.amazon.com/gp/product/B07Y1PSS27/) which just has a single USB C port.  I want to be able to use a keyboard and charge the tablet at the same time.  [A previous post here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/195120/is-it-possible-to-charge-and-transfer-files-to-an-android-phone-with-a-usb-c-hub) says that is possible.

However, I can't get it to work.  I'm using [this hub](https://smile.amazon.com/gp/product/B07QQ11BP6/) and [this keyboard](https://smile.amazon.com/gp/product/B016MAK38U/).  When I plug the keyboard into the hub, the keyboard's backlight comes on for about a second and then turns off.  After that, the keyboard is non-responsive.  (No backlight, no caps lock LED, and typing on it doesn't have any effect.)

What do I need to do to make this work?

**Additional Information:**

- The tablet is running Android 9, kernel version 4.4.147.
- The Redragon keyboard works fine on my MacBook Pro.
- I tried the USB-C hub with the Redragon keyboard and charger on my LG G7 ThinQ, and it worked successfully.  (Keyboard works, and the phone charges.)  The phone is running Android 9, kernel version 4.9.112.  I do not have any non-Android devices (Windows, Mac, or Linux) with a USB-C port to test with.
- The charger I'm using with the hub is the same charger that came with the tablet.  It is 5 volts, 2 amps.  The charger has a USB A port, and connects to the tablet via a USB A to USB C cable.
- The tablet charges when connected directly to the charger.  But when I put the hub in between the tablet and the charger, it does not charge.  So I should probably get this part working before even worrying about the keyboard.
- If my goal was just to charge and use a keyboard, I know it would probably be easier to just use a Bluetooth keyboard.  However, I would like to use other features of the hub, such as plugging in a USB flash drive, or possibly even using the Ethernet port which is built into the hub.

Comment: Are you powering the hub with a power adapter?

Comment: I've tried it both with and without the charger connected to the hub, and it doesn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: Just to make sure: 1) you've tested the mechanical keyboard on a regular PC and it works 2) you've tested the USB hub on a different device (phone or laptop) and it works i.e. you can read files from a usb drive plugged into the hub, or something else other than just charging 3) have you tried the tablet + usb hub with a different known working keyboard 4) Also when you say you've used the charger to power the hub - which charger and how much power (watts or voltage/amps) does it support.

Comment: To my experience when using a keyboard like yours via OTG you often run into problems if the keyboard is a fancy one like your with additional lighting or integrated USB hub and/or smartcard reader. For using a keyboard with Android therefore prefer a very simple keyboard with no extras. In your case you should think about using a Bluetooth keyboard as it would simplify the set-up.

Comment: @MorrisonChang I've added additional information to my post which should answer your questions.

Comment: Have you tried with LG G7 ThinQ charger to USB hub to tablet? If the hub & the LG phone works, then my concern is that the tablet: may not support USB-Power Delivery which is required for PC/Mac charging by the hub. If you bought the LG phone, you may have a USB-A female to USB-C male connector which is used for old phone to new phone setup, If so, use that dongle to see if the keyboard works (on both devices).

Comment: The G7 ThinQ did not come with an A-to-C dongle, but I bought a dongle on Amazon.  Yes, the keyboard works with the tablet when using the dongle.  I haven't seen the G7 ThinQ charger in a long time; it's running around the house somewhere with other chargers, but I haven't been able to find it.  It was very similar to the tablet charger, though, in that it had a female USB-A port.  I suspect it was also 2A, but I can't find it to confirm.